# Can't change JavaScript variable created inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm stuck in this problem for days.

1- User press one of the buttons.
2- The button pressed insert a .js variable inside **LABEL->lbJavaScriptVar**
3- **Sys.Application.add_load(GridJson);** calls the .js function

The problem is, **i can't change the variable "SHOWTHIS" value inside an UpdatePanel** the value never change

-----------------------------[aspx]------------------------------------

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GridJson()
    {
        alert(SHOWTHIS);
        document.getElementById("Grid").innerHTML = 
                "<tr><td>" + SHOWTHIS+ "</td></tr>"
    }            
</script>
</head>
```

...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:Button ID="btMan" runat="server" OnClick="btMan_click" Text="Man"/>
<asp:Button ID="btWoman" runat="server" OnClick="btWoman_click" Text="Woman"/>

<asp:Label ID="lbJavaScriptVar" runat="server" ></asp:Label>

<table id="Grid" border="5" class="cssMiniGrid"></table>
<script type="text/javascript">Sys.Application.add_load(GridJson);</script>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

-----------------------------[/aspx]------------------------------------

-----------------------------[.cs]------------------------------------

```
(btMan_click)...
lbJavaScriptVar.Text = "<script> var SHOWTHIS= 9999</script> ";

(btWoman_click)...
lbJavaScriptVar.Text = "<script> var SHOWTHIS = 7777</script> ";
```

-----------------------------[/.cs]------------------------------------

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

**EDITED**...I made it thanks to your sugestions, edit these lines to make it work

```
.ASPX<
[ALTER]function GridJson() ------> function GridJson(SHOWTHIS) {

.CS
[DELETE](btMan_click)... 
[DELETE]lbJavaScriptVar.Text = "<script> var SHOWTHIS= 9999</script> ";   
[DELETE](btWoman_click)... 
[DELETE]lbJavaScriptVar.Text = "<script> var SHOWTHIS = 7777</script> "; 
[INCLUDE]ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "", "GridJson(" + "THANKS" + ");", true);
```

Note: I made this code at first inside a web user control, now the code is under the root page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try simply in this way

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "", "myFunction('value');", true);
```

then in javascript

```
function myFunction(parameter){
   SHOWTHIS= parameter;
}
```

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bahh2fef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: this way the .js function will be called just the first time...when i press another button the method don't answer

Comment: replace RegisterStartupScript with RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: Still call just one time :( ...i can make it call infinite times with Sys.Application.add_load(GridJson); but this way every change i make in js variables is ignored

Comment: I think that there is something else wrong. It should be good now. Try debugging if the call arrives to the javascript function. Has your updatepanel the trigger for both buttons click events?

Answer (score 0):

Append script using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx